# Is there any way to know if a link was shared (sent)?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like

Along with the Like button, there is a "Send" button, whose functionality is similar to the deprecated "Share" button. I'd like to know if there is a programmatically way to know if a particular user successfully shared a link.

I am thinking about offering rewards on my website to those who share a link on facebook, but in order to do that. I need to be able to track which user shared the link.

My possible solution is to share a unique URL per user, and then track the referer, but I do not know how reliable that method is, or how abusable it is, I think it would be easier if facebook provide some kind of callback function, so I can keep track which user sent a link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am thinking about offering rewards on my website to those who share a link on facebook

That would be against [platform policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) – see section *IV. Application Integration Points, #1*:

> “You must not incentivize users to use […] Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.”

Comment: I didn't know that, how come there are many pages that offer incentives as long as you share a link? 

For instance, I've seen many times "Like this to Download this file", isn't that some kind of incentive?

Comment: There are so many pages doing this because they have not been caught doing it yet …

Comment: Well, even though you did not answer my question per se, you gave me a very good reason not to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

You can subscribe to the "message.sent" event and call your server with an ajax request when the event is triggered.

FB.Event.subscribe('message.sent'',
    function(response) {
        alert('Track that someone shared the URL: ' + response);
    }
);